# UIImagePickerController delegate method not called (delegate set to self)

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

I have a problem where:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {}
```

only gets called with the camera, not when I am trying to chose an image by browsing through the user's photos.

here is my initialization code for the UIImagePicker delegate:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{

    [self initImagePicker];

}


-(void)initImagePicker{
    DLog(@"");

    self.imagePickerController.delegate = self;

}



- (void)setupImagePicker:(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType)sourceType
{
    self.imagePickerController.sourceType = sourceType;

    if (sourceType == UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera)
    {
        // user wants to use the camera interface
        //
        self.imagePickerController.showsCameraControls = NO;

        if ([[self.imagePickerController.cameraOverlayView subviews] count] == 0)
        {
            // setup our custom overlay view for the camera
            //
            // ensure that our custom view's frame fits within the parent frame
            CGRect overlayViewFrame = self.imagePickerController.cameraOverlayView.frame;

            CGRect newFrame = CGRectMake(0.0,CGRectGetHeight(overlayViewFrame)-15.0,CGRectGetWidth(overlayViewFrame),15.0);

            self.view.frame = newFrame;
            [self.imagePickerController.cameraOverlayView addSubview:self.view];
            [self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.view];
        }
    }
}
```

then in my root class, the one that is the delegate to the class UIImagePicker that is the delegate to the UIImagePicker:

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Toolbar Actions

- (void)showImagePicker:(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType)sourceType
{




    if (![UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
    {
        // camera is not on this device, don't show the camera button
        NSMutableArray *toolbarItems = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:self.myToolbar.items.count];
        [toolbarItems addObjectsFromArray:self.myToolbar.items];
        [toolbarItems removeObjectAtIndex:2];
        [self.myToolbar setItems:toolbarItems animated:NO];
    }

    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:sourceType])
    {


        self.overlayViewController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"OverlayViewController"];
        self.overlayViewController.delegate = self;

        self.overlayViewController.imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        [self.overlayViewController setupImagePicker:sourceType];
        [self presentModalViewController:self.overlayViewController.imagePickerController animated:YES];
    }
}
```

I know this is a lot of code for a SO question, but to the people experienced with implementing this class, what am I doing wrong?

To me, this line is weird:

```
 self.overlayViewController.imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
```

I've never allocated and initialized a property outside of the owner before. Is that the issue?

Comment: from where did you call the  `setupImagePicker` and `showImagePicker`

Comment: setUpImagePicker is called within the UIImagePicker delegate view controller that appears when showImagePicker is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the fix:

need to add:

```
self.overlayViewController.imagePickerController.delegate = self.overlayViewController;
```

after:

```
self.overlayViewController.imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
```

Comment: stackOverflow you did the same what @tobiasbayer suggested you to do earlier, but you didn't mark his answer correct! great way to earn the points!

Answer (score 6):

I think you are setting the delegate too early (`initImagePicker` in `viewDidLoad`). `self.imagePickerController` might be nil there. 
You should set the delegate after you create the `UIImagePickerController`.

Comment: !! lol you might have beat me to it. I Just posted my answer too please accept the edits and will accept your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Set UIImagePickerDelegate and UINavigationControllerDelegate in .h file in to with @interface.

As like

```
@interface class : UIView <UIImagePickerDelegate , UINavigationControllerDelegate>
```

With UIImagePickerController object set self delegate too,

```
imgPickerController.delegate = self;
```

Hope it helps you too.